# Background Service Video Recorder in Android 10 (Q)

Tags: android, service, background, camera, recording

I am developing an application that works only by android services, with no user action.

I would like to create a background video recorder that only uses a service.
I found several projects but they were too old (they are around 5 years old each) like this : https://github.com/pickerweng/CameraRecorder

The Android documentation is not very conciliatory. It would seem that SurfaceView is a solution but unfortunately it can only be created in an activity.

Anyone have any leads possibly using Camera2?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the camera on Android Q or later unless you're a foreground application, or foreground service (with a persistent notification).

That said, if you are one of those cases, you can use either the deprecated camera API or the newer camera2 API without drawing preview.

For the old API, you can just use a SurfaceTexture as a preview output, and never do anything with the SurfaceTexture otherwise; for camera2, just set up a recording output Surface, and no preview output Surface.

Comment: It does not matter if there is a notification...
I just don't want to use any Activity.
Do you have any idea of code I can use with a foreground service and a persistent notification ?

Comment: I'm not aware of sample code that implements what I suggest. I would probably try to adapt camera2video, by removing the preview output target and moving it to be a foreground service instead of an activity: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/Camera2Video

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working implementation of a background recording app using CameraX:

**1) Here is the background service**

```
    class MediaRecordingService : LifecycleService() {

    companion object {
        const val CHANNEL_ID: String = "media_recorder_service"
        private val TAG = MediaRecordingService::class.simpleName
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        const val CHANNEL_NAME: String = "Media recording service"
        const val ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID: Int = 2345
        const val ACTION_START_WITH_PREVIEW: String = "start_recording"
        const val BIND_USECASE: String = "bind_usecase"
    }

    enum class RecordingState {
        RECORDING, PAUSED, STOPPED
    }

    class RecordingServiceBinder(private val service: MediaRecordingService) : Binder() {
        fun getService(): MediaRecordingService {
            return service
        }
    }
    private var preview: Preview? = null
    private lateinit var timer: Timer
    private var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider? = null
    private lateinit var recordingServiceBinder: RecordingServiceBinder
    private var activeRecording: ActiveRecording? = null
    private var videoCapture: androidx.camera.video.VideoCapture<Recorder>? = null
    private val listeners = HashSet<DataListener>(1)
    private val pendingActions: HashMap<String, Runnable> = hashMapOf()
    private var recordingState: RecordingState = RecordingState.STOPPED
    private var duration: Int = 0
    private var timerTask: TimerTask? = null
    private var isSoundEnabled: Boolean = true

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        recordingServiceBinder = RecordingServiceBinder(this)
        timer = Timer()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        when(intent?.action) {
            ACTION_START_WITH_PREVIEW -> {
                if (cameraProvider == null) {
                    initializeCamera()
                }
            }
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    private fun initializeCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val qualitySelector = getQualitySelector()
            val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
                .setQualitySelector(qualitySelector)
                .build()
            videoCapture = withOutput(recorder)
                        // Select back camera as a default
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider?.unbindAll()
                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, videoCapture)
            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(MediaRecordingService::class.simpleName, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }
            val action = pendingActions[BIND_USECASE]
            action?.run()
            pendingActions.remove(BIND_USECASE)
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun getQualitySelector(): QualitySelector {
        return QualitySelector
            .firstTry(QualitySelector.QUALITY_UHD)
            .thenTry(QualitySelector.QUALITY_FHD)
            .thenTry(QualitySelector.QUALITY_HD)
            .finallyTry(
                QualitySelector.QUALITY_SD,
                QualitySelector.FALLBACK_STRATEGY_LOWER
            )
    }

    fun startRecording() {
        val mediaStoreOutputOptions = createMediaStoreOutputOptions()
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }

        var pendingRecording = videoCapture?.output?.prepareRecording(this, mediaStoreOutputOptions)
        if (isSoundEnabled) {
            pendingRecording = pendingRecording?.withAudioEnabled()
        }
        activeRecording = pendingRecording?.withEventListener(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                {
                    when (it) {
                        is VideoRecordEvent.Start -> {
                            startTrackingTime()
                            recordingState = RecordingState.RECORDING
                        }

                        is VideoRecordEvent.Finalize -> {
                            recordingState = RecordingState.STOPPED
                            duration = 0
                            timerTask?.cancel()
                        }
                    }
                    for (listener in listeners) {
                        listener.onRecordingEvent(it)
                    }
                })
            ?.start()
        recordingState = RecordingState.RECORDING
    }

    private fun startTrackingTime() {
        timerTask = object: TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                if (recordingState == RecordingState.RECORDING) {
                    duration += 1
                    for (listener in listeners) {
                        listener.onNewData(duration)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 1000, 1000)
    }

    fun stopRecording() {
        activeRecording?.stop()
        activeRecording = null
    }

    private fun createMediaStoreOutputOptions(): MediaStoreOutputOptions {
        val name = "CameraX-recording-" +
                SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault())
                    .format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".mp4"
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/Recorded Videos")
            }
        }
        return MediaStoreOutputOptions.Builder(
            contentResolver,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        )
            .setContentValues(contentValues)
            .build()
    }

    fun bindPreviewUseCase(surfaceProvider: Preview.SurfaceProvider?) {
        activeRecording?.pause()
        if (cameraProvider != null) {
            bindInternal(surfaceProvider)
        } else {
            pendingActions[BIND_USECASE] = Runnable {
                bindInternal(surfaceProvider)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun bindInternal(surfaceProvider: Preview.SurfaceProvider?) {
        if (preview != null) {
            cameraProvider?.unbind(preview)
        }
        initPreviewUseCase()
        preview?.setSurfaceProvider(surfaceProvider)
        val cameraInfo: CameraInfo? = cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(
            this@MediaRecordingService,
            CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,
            preview
        )?.cameraInfo
        observeCameraState(cameraInfo, this)
    }

    private fun initPreviewUseCase() {
        preview?.setSurfaceProvider(null)
        preview = Preview.Builder()
            .build()
    }

    fun unbindPreview() {
        // Just remove the surface provider. I discovered that for some reason if you unbind the Preview usecase the camera willl stop recording the video.
        preview?.setSurfaceProvider(null)
    }

    fun startRunningInForeground() {
        val parentStack = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            .addNextIntentWithParentStack(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))

        val pendingIntent1 = parentStack.getPendingIntent(0, 0)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            val nm = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            nm.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.video_recording))
            .setContentText(getText(R.string.video_recording_in_background))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_record)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent1)
            .build()
        startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    }

    fun isSoundEnabled(): Boolean {
        return isSoundEnabled
    }

    fun setSoundEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
        isSoundEnabled = enabled
    }

    // Stop recording and remove SurfaceView
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        activeRecording?.stop()
        timerTask?.cancel()
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        super.onBind(intent)
        return recordingServiceBinder
    }

    fun addListener(listener: DataListener) {
        listeners.add(listener)
    }

    fun removeListener(listener: DataListener) {
        listeners.remove(listener)
    }

    fun getRecordingState(): RecordingState {
        return recordingState
    }

    private fun observeCameraState(cameraInfo: androidx.camera.core.CameraInfo?, context: Context) {
        cameraInfo?.cameraState?.observe(this) { cameraState ->
            run {
                when (cameraState.type) {
                    CameraState.Type.PENDING_OPEN -> {
                        // Ask the user to close other camera apps
                    }
                    CameraState.Type.OPENING -> {
                        // Show the Camera UI
                        for (listener in listeners) {
                            listener.onCameraOpened()
                        }
                    }
                    CameraState.Type.OPEN -> {
                        // Setup Camera resources and begin processing
                    }
                    CameraState.Type.CLOSING -> {
                        // Close camera UI
                    }
                    CameraState.Type.CLOSED -> {
                        // Free camera resources
                    }
                }
            }

            cameraState.error?.let { error ->
                when (error.code) {
                    // Open errors
                    CameraState.ERROR_STREAM_CONFIG -> {
                        // Make sure to setup the use cases properly
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Stream config error. Restart application",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    // Opening errors
                    CameraState.ERROR_CAMERA_IN_USE -> {
                        // Close the camera or ask user to close another camera app that's using the
                        // camera
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Camera in use. Close any apps that are using the camera",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    CameraState.ERROR_MAX_CAMERAS_IN_USE -> {
                        // Close another open camera in the app, or ask the user to close another
                        // camera app that's using the camera
                    }
                    CameraState.ERROR_OTHER_RECOVERABLE_ERROR -> {

                    }
                    // Closing errors
                    CameraState.ERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED -> {
                         // Ask the user to enable the device's cameras
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Camera disabled",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    CameraState.ERROR_CAMERA_FATAL_ERROR -> {
                        // Ask the user to reboot the device to restore camera function
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Fatal error",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    // Closed errors
                    CameraState.ERROR_DO_NOT_DISTURB_MODE_ENABLED -> {
                        // Ask the user to disable the "Do Not Disturb" mode, then reopen the camera
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Do not disturb mode enabled",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    interface DataListener {
        fun onNewData(duration: Int)
        fun onCameraOpened()
        fun onRecordingEvent(it: VideoRecordEvent?)
    }

    }
```

**Add these dependencies**

```
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:1.1.0-alpha11"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-alpha11"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-alpha11"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha31"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha31"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.4.0"
```

**2) Here is the activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MediaRecordingService.DataListener {
    private var recordingService: MediaRecordingService? = null
    private lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var isReverseLandscape: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)
        viewBinding.btnRecord.setOnClickListener {
            onPauseRecordClicked()
        }
        viewBinding.btnMute.setOnClickListener { onMuteRecordingClicked() }
        viewBinding.btnRotate.setOnClickListener {
            requestedOrientation = if (isReverseLandscape) {
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
            } else {
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE
            }
            isReverseLandscape = !isReverseLandscape
        }
        viewBinding.btnBack.setOnClickListener {
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    private fun onMuteRecordingClicked() {
        if(recordingService == null) return
        var soundEnabled = recordingService?.isSoundEnabled()
        soundEnabled = !soundEnabled!!
        recordingService?.setSoundEnabled(soundEnabled)
        setSoundState(soundEnabled)
    }

    private fun setSoundState(soundEnabled: Boolean) {
        if (soundEnabled){
            viewBinding.viewMute.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_volume_up_24)
        } else {
            viewBinding.viewMute.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_volume_off_24)
        }
    }

    private fun bindService() {
        val intent = Intent(this, MediaRecordingService::class.java)
        intent.action = MediaRecordingService.ACTION_START_WITH_PREVIEW
        startService(intent)
        bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        bindService()
    }

    private val serviceConnection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder?) {
            recordingService = (service as MediaRecordingService.RecordingServiceBinder).getService()
            onServiceBound(recordingService)
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName?) {

        }
    }

    private fun onServiceBound(recordingService: MediaRecordingService?) {
        when(recordingService?.getRecordingState()){
            MediaRecordingService.RecordingState.RECORDING -> {
                viewBinding.viewRecordPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_stop_24)
                viewBinding.btnMute.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
            MediaRecordingService.RecordingState.STOPPED -> {
                viewBinding.viewRecordPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_videocam_24)
                viewBinding.txtDuration.text = "00:00:00"
                viewBinding.btnMute.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                setSoundState(recordingService.isSoundEnabled())
            }
            else -> {
                // no-op
            }
        }

        recordingService?.addListener(this)
        recordingService?.bindPreviewUseCase(viewBinding.previewContainer.surfaceProvider)
    }

    private fun onPauseRecordClicked() {
        when(recordingService?.getRecordingState()){
            MediaRecordingService.RecordingState.RECORDING -> {
                recordingService?.stopRecording()
                viewBinding.viewRecordPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_videocam_24)
                viewBinding.txtDuration.text = "00:00:00"
            }
            MediaRecordingService.RecordingState.STOPPED -> {
                viewBinding.viewRecordPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_stop_24)
                recordingService?.startRecording()
            }
            else -> {
                // no-op
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onNewData(duration: Int) {
        runOnUiThread {
            var seconds = duration
            var minutes = seconds / MINUTE
            seconds %= MINUTE
            val hours = minutes / HOUR
            minutes %= HOUR

            val hoursString = if (hours >= 10) hours.toString() else "0$hours"
            val minutesString = if (minutes >= 10) minutes.toString() else "0$minutes"
            val secondsString = if (seconds >= 10) seconds.toString() else "0$seconds"
            viewBinding.txtDuration.text = "$hoursString:$minutesString:$secondsString"
        }
    }

    override fun onCameraOpened() {

    }

    override fun onRecordingEvent(it: VideoRecordEvent?) {
        when (it) {
            is VideoRecordEvent.Start -> {
                viewBinding.btnMute.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                viewBinding.viewRecordPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_stop_24)
            }

            is VideoRecordEvent.Finalize -> {
                recordingService?.isSoundEnabled()?.let { it1 -> setSoundState(it1) }
                viewBinding.btnMute.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                viewBinding.viewRecordPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_videocam_24)
                onNewData(0)
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, it.outputResults.outputUri)
                intent.setDataAndType(it.outputResults.outputUri, "video/mp4")
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open recorded video"))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if (recordingService?.getRecordingState() == MediaRecordingService.RecordingState.STOPPED) {
            recordingService?.let {
                ServiceCompat.stopForeground(it, ServiceCompat.STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE)
                recordingService?.stopSelf()
            }
        } else {
            recordingService?.startRunningInForeground()
        }
        recordingService?.unbindPreview()
        recordingService?.removeListener(this)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val MINUTE: Int = 60
        private const val HOUR: Int = MINUTE * 60
    }
}
```

3. And in the manifest these permissions

```html
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

And here is the activity layout:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.theorbapp.MainActivity">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/preview_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent_black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            tools:text="00:01:25" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_rotate"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_radius"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_radius"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_drawable"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_back"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_back"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn_back">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_inner_radius"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_inner_radius"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_screen_rotation_24" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_radius"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_radius"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_drawable"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_navigate_before_24" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_record"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_drawable"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_mute"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn_back"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_back">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_record_pause"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_videocam_24" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_mute"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_radius"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_radius"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_drawable"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_mute"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_inner_radius"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_inner_radius"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_volume_up_24" />
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This implementation records video in the background. However the bug I have discovered is that sometimes when you open the app coming back from background recording the preview gets black. I have tried to fix this bug to no avail